# Any way other than scripting to back up data for one month of a single table in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I have actually built an application using C# to do differential backup with compression option on daily to reduce bak file size and increase the speed of backup. However, the file size is still too large for me. So I plan to backup the whole database but I want one of a table (that contain the most data) to contain only one month data. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: how "Big" is big?  one thing you can do is archive older data to a secondary database you backup once a week/month.  leaving smaller active data

Comment: If your backup is too big, do you have enough space to restore? Sounds like you have bigger problems going on here.

Comment: See the command line tools from msdn.  You can create .bat files to automatically do the backups : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: the bak file is just 60 gb. But a smaller file size is required.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken what you meant by large is you tried to backup the whole database and it require more time and processing power.

I assume that you don't have the privileges to modify the table in the original database. Maybe you can try using this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp
to copy the rows that you can set in the "WHERE" statement to another table (external database) and then backup it.